# NextJS' Image doesn't work good with Tailwind

Tags: image, hover, next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I am building an e-commerce project using NextJS and Tailwind. I am using Next's Image component for displaying product pictures but when I try to use Tailwind's hover effects on the Image nothing happens.

Well, not ALL hover effects have the problem. Trying to change the opacity works just fine, but trying to use scale or skew on hover has no impact.

Anyone else had the same issue? If so, did you manage to find a fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried?